# Find the tangential and normal components of the acceleration vector for the curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the tangential and normal components of the acceleration vector for the curve

$$ \vec r  (t) = 〈 2t,t^2 ,\ln t 〉$$

I found this problem in a notebook and I did a part, but I was stuck and I don't know if I was doing it correctly. If you can help me it would be great. Thanks!

$$r'(t)= v(t)=<2,2t,1/t>$$
$$v'(t)=<0,2,-1/t^2>$$
$$\Vert r'(t)\Vert=  \sqrt{4+4t^2+1/t^2}=2t+1/t. $$
$$<-4/t,-2/t^2,4>$$
$$k(t)=\frac{4t^3+2t}{(2t^2+1)^3}$$
$$a_T=<0,2,-1/t^2>$$
$$a_N=<4,4t^2,1/t^2>$$

I've come here and I do not know if it's this way or how?Sorry for the mistakes I'm starting to use the page.

Comment: Is $a_T+a_N=v'$?

Comment: I cannot understand where this $<-4/t,-2/t^2,4>$ comes from

Comment: I even asked the teacher and told me that aT is a scalar not a vector and that was not the way I did it and therefore I do not understand if there is another way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Outline:

Position:
$$ \vec r  (t) = < 2t, t^2 , \ln t >$$

Velocity:
$$ \vec v(t)= < 2,2t,1/t>$$

Acceleration:
$$\vec a (t)=<0,2,-1/t^2>$$

Speed:
$$ v(t) = \Vert \vec v(t)\Vert=  \sqrt{4+4t^2+1/t^2}=2t+1/t  $$

The unit vector in the direction of the velocity is
$$
\vec u(t) =
\frac{\vec v(t)}{ v(t)}
=
\frac{1}{2t+1/t} 
< 2,2t,1/t>
$$

The tangential component of the acceleration $a_T(t)$ can be found by $a_T(t) = \vec a(t) \cdot \vec u (t)$

The normal component of the acceleration, $\vec a_N$ can then be found using $\vec a(t) = a_T (t) \vec u_T(t) + a_N (t) \vec u_N(t)$.